Azure Pipeline Dacpack SQL Server issue
We are updating schema by running ALTER SCHEMA command for existing tables and other objects in Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU22) (KB4577467). As a part of steps we are first creating the premigration script and running it manually which is properly migrating the schema.
At the same time we are updating our SQL Server DB Project with the changes aligned with the premigration script so that there should not be any changes surfacing while running the Azure DB pipeline.
But we observed that after running the pipeline, the DB Pipeline is corrupting the database with either merging columns of other tables or dropping and recreating the tables.

Kindly suggest how we can prevent these sort of changes, what is causing error. Do you suggest any better approach to achieve it.
Trying to update the schema of existing objects on SQL Server 2017 On AWS cloud

Azure Db pipeline are you rfering to devops?

Yes, it is Azure pipeline for database deployment

SqlPackage does not do any magic transformations. Shown picture are of no use - we have no idea what you're showing. I see two different tables. Show your pipeline settings, premigration script, project sources, publish script. At least minimal related piece of mentioned stuff.
